# How to Click on the <textarea> as per the HTML below?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm working on a huge automation project and this is my LAST ISSUE before I can wrap up this project. I'm using Selenium to automate changes on a Drupal style website. Thus far, I have been able to click and interact with every web-element on the site (especially once I stopped using the chrome driver, which for whatever reason cannot click elements wrapped in `<div>` tags?). Anyway, I've found recently that (while using the FireFox geckodriver, FYI) I cannot click on [`<textarea>` web-elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVr0V.png). When doing so I get the following error:

```
Element <textarea id="edit-body-und-0-value" class="text-full wysiwyg form-textarea wysiwyg-processed" name="body[und][0][value]"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Here is my corresponding code and HTML:

Java

```
WebElement description = driver.findElement(By.id("edit-body-und-0-value"));
description.click();
description.clear();
description.sendKeys(desiredString);
```

HTML

```
<div class="field-type-text-with-summary field-name-body field-widget-text-textarea-with-summary form-wrapper" id="edit-body">
    <div id="body-add-more-wrapper">
        <div class="text-format-wrapper">
            <div class="text-summary-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-body-und-0-value">
                <label for="edit-body-und-0-value">Description </label>
                <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable"><textarea class="text-full wysiwyg form-textarea" id="edit-body-und-0-value" name="body[und][0][value]" cols="60" rows="20">&lt;p&gt;Specific projects are dependent on students&amp;#39; interests, backgrounds, and classes completed.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea></div>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="filter-wrapper form-wrapper" id="edit-body-und-0-format">
                <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                    <div class="filter-help form-wrapper" id="edit-body-und-0-format-help">
                        <p><a href="/filter/tips" target="_blank">More information about text formats</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-body-und-0-format">
                        <label for="edit-body-und-0-format--2">Text format </label>
                        <select class="filter-list form-select" id="edit-body-und-0-format--2" name="body[und][0][format]"><option value="filtered_html" selected="selected">Filtered HTML</option><option value="full_html">Full HTML</option><option value="plain_text">Plain text</option></select>
                    </div>
```

I have used many different ways of finding the web-element and can promise this method brings up the correct text-area element. I have even tried clicking on the `<div>` element itself, but to no avail. The following methods have also failed:

Using the Action library in Selenium like so:

```
Actions desc = new Actions(driver);
desc.moveToElement(description).click();
Action doIt = desc.build();
doIt.perform();
```

Fails with: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: TypeError: rect is undefined`

Using the Javascript Executor does nothing save scroll to the element. Clicking just clicks the top right corner of the screen.

Using a `WebDriverWait` object times out because the element is never made clickable in time.

I have no idea what is making clicking on this element so hard, but I think I came across a clue today. I'm no expert on how JQuery (or JS in general) works, but this script is at the top of the page:

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":....
```

In the fairly large script, the only element ID's that are  elements are attached to an object called "triggers". Here is the portion of the script:

```
 "triggers": {
            "edit-field-office-address-und-0-value": {
                "field": "edit-field-office-address-und-0-value",
                "resizable": 1,
                "select": "edit-field-office-address-und-0-format--2",
                "formatfiltered_html": {
                    "editor": "ckeditor",
                    "status": 1,
                    "toggle": 1
                }
            },
            "edit-body-und-0-value": {
                "field": "edit-body-und-0-value",
                "resizable": 1,
                "select": "edit-body-und-0-format--2",
                "formatfiltered_html": {
                    "editor": "ckeditor",
                    "status": 1,
                    "toggle": 1
                }
            },
            "edit-field-requirements-und-0-value": {
                "field": "edit-field-requirements-und-0-value",
                "resizable": 1,
                "select": "edit-field-requirements-und-0-format--2",
                "formatfiltered_html": {
                    "editor": "ckeditor",
                    "status": 1,
                    "toggle": 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I'm thinking the Javascript somehow messes up the click option. Maybe it creates the formatting options which then makes the element seem unclickable?

I have no idea what to do and the deadline is near approaching! I would appreciate any help figuring out how to click and interact with this text area!

Answer (score 0):

You can use try below

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)

//Present in DOM
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement(By.id("ID")));

//scroll to view
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ID")));  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

//Click
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ID")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem before wherein elements are not captured by the driver when they are not screen even though they are present on the web page (you have to scroll up or down in order to handle them). Upon checking on my project, I found out that the issue was caused by an outdated chrome driver.

Here are my suggested solutions:

1. Try debugging, setting a break point just before you find your textarea element. When debug execution pauses at your break point, scroll your page such that the textarea is visible. Continue the execution. If the issue was still encountered, you may have to check your selector. But if there were no issues encountered with the manual scroll intervention, then it may be a driver/browser problem.
2. Make sure your Chrome driver is updated as well as the Chrome browser installed on your machine. The latest release of the Chrome driver is usually posted here:
   http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
3. If updating your driver/browser did not work or is not applicable, as a work around, you can try inserting page-up or page-down actions before getting your element with Actions builder.

Here is a sample code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions
        .moveToElement(anyVisibleElement)
        .sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP)
        .build()
        .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the text area with default text as **Specific projects are dependent on students' interests, backgrounds, and classes completed.** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("textarea.text-full.wysiwyg.form-textarea#edit-body-und-0-value>p"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//textarea[@class='text-full wysiwyg form-textarea' and @id='edit-body-und-0-value']/p"))).click();
  ```

Comment: This fails with a "waiting for element to be clickable" error :/